# Socket.io pass array to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, chat

I'm trying to pass an array called "usernames" to the client.
Here's the code on the server side:

```
var usernames = {};
var numUsers = 0;

    socket.on('online users', function () {
        io.emit('connected_users', {
            name: usernames,
            total: numUsers
        });
    });
```

Here's the client site:

```
          var online=[]
          var onlineNum=0;

          function headcount(){
            socket.emit('online users');
          }

          socket.on('connected_users', function (data){
            onlineNum=data.total;
            for(i=0; i<onlineNum; i++){
                online[i]=data.name[i];
                alert(data.name[i]);}
          });
```

The alert is simply "Undefined".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: @Matt, you're right. It's {} and not []! Didn't notice that.
Any idea on how to pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found an answer to this!

```
socket.on('connected_users', function (data){
        onlinecounter=data.total;
        alert(data.total);
        for (var key in data.name) {
            online[i]=key;
            alert(key);
        }
      });
```

That solves my problem as like said by @Matt, the usernames variable is actually an object with property:key equal to username:username, and I only need the property name or key of it. In this case, I'm getting the key.